# How to create a linked list using a struct inside the node element

Tags: linked-list, malloc

I tried to create a linked list,  using a node that had a structure inside it to hold the info data. Whenever I try to do that , I have a compiled error telling me that I am using an "incomplete" type,  and I am not sure why.

The exact error I have  is the following:

```
main.c: In function ‘createList’:
main.c:53:46: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘typeNode’ {aka ‘struct StructInfoNodo’}
   53 | if ((new_node = (typeNode *) malloc (sizeof (typeNode))) == NULL)
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~
main.c:59:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘typeNode’ {aka ‘struct StructInfoNodo’}
   59 | new_node->info.idCell=nodeinfo.idCell;
      |         ^~
main2.c:67:5: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   67 | list->num_nodes;
      | ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

In my code,  I have  a createList funtion, which tries to create the first node of the list, using some sample data. However, I am unable to the initial malloc, seems it does not recognize the new type that was defined (typeNet) to hold the info inside a structure.

I was using  for that the following instruct:  new_node = (typeNode *) malloc (sizeof (typeNode))
and after that, I was trying to do new_node->info.idCell=nodeinfo.idCell;

That lines result in the errors shown above.

Any idea on how I can solve it, and be able to write info on the node?

Please find below the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXCHAR 80

struct structInfoNet   
{
    int idCell;
    char MacAddress[MAXCHAR];
    char Essid[MAXCHAR];
    char Mode[MAXCHAR];
    int Channel;
};

typedef struct structInfoNet typeNet;

struct structInfoNode
{
    typeNet info;
    struct structInfoNode* nextNode;
};

typedef struct StructInfoNodo typeNode;

/* Struct to store pointers to firs & last element linked list */
struct structInfoLista {
    
    typeNode *firstNode;
    typeNode *lastNode;
    
    int num_nodes;
};

typedef struct structInfoLista typeInfoList;

/* Initialitate frist & last elements  linked list */
void initLinkedList (typeInfoList *list){

list->firstNode = NULL;

list->lastNode = NULL;

list->num_nodes= 0;

}

/* Insert First Element on the List (CreateList) */
int createList (typeInfoList * list, typeNet nodeinfo) {

typeNode *new_node;

if ((new_node = (typeNode *) malloc (sizeof (typeNode))) == NULL) 
{
    printf ("Error. Unable to create node");
    return -1;
}

new_node->info.idCell=nodeinfo.idCell;

new_node->nextNode = NULL;

list->firstNode = new_node;

list->lastNode = new_node;

list->num_nodes;

return 0;

}


int main()
{

    typeNet net;
    typeInfoList *list;

    // Get memory to store struct with pointers to first & last Nodes
    if ((list = (typeInfoList *) malloc (sizeof (typeInfoList))) == NULL) 
    {
        printf ("Error!!  Unable to get memory");
        exit (1);
    } 

    

    //Create auxiliar list to store pointers to first & last nodes
    initLinkedList (list);
    // Sample data to add to first element of the list
    net.idCell=5;

    //Create initial linked list  (first element)
    createList (list, net);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
typedef struct StructInfoNodo typeNode;
```

should be

```
typedef struct structInfoNodo typeNode;
```